Continuous injective function $f:\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^{n\times m}$ ($n,m\geq 2$) that commutes with permutations?
Is there an invertible function $f:\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^m \to X$ for $X\subseteq \mathbb R^{n\times m}$ for $n\geq 2$ and $m\geq 2$, which commutes with permutations, meaning for any permutations $\mu$ on $\{1,...,n\}$ and $\pi$ on $\{1,...,m\}$ we have:
$$f((x_{\mu(1)},..,x_{\mu(n)}),(y_{\pi(1)},..,y_{\pi(m)}))_{ij}
=f(x,y)_{\mu(i),\pi(j)}$$
Ideally, we'd want $f$ to be continuous, though this is of secondary importance.
Does such an $f$ exist?

Another way of writing this is: Let $p:\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m$ transform according to the permutations $\mu,\pi$, so that $p(x,y)= ((x_{\mu(1)},..,x_{\mu(n)}),(y_{\pi(1)},..,y_{\pi(m)}))$. Similarly, overload $p:\mathbb R^{n\times m}\to \mathbb R^{n\times m}$ so that it maps $p(A)_{i,j}=A_{\mu(i),\pi(j)}$. Then
$$f(p(x,y))=p(f(x,y))$$

Note, such an $f$ would have the nice property that $p(x,y) = f^{-1}(p(f(x,y)))$.
The best I could come up with is $f$ as the outer product, but this is only invertible up to a scalar, since $xy^T=(cx)(\frac 1 cy)^T$.

$f$ being continuous is impossible. Indeed, let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, $\hat{a} = (a, \cdots, a) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $\hat{b} = (b, \cdots, b) \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Since any pair of permutations $\mu, \pi$ leaves both $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ intact, your condition implies $f(\hat{a}, \hat{b})$ is a constant vector - all its coordinates are the same. So, $\mathbb{R}^2 \ni (a, b) \mapsto f(\hat{a}, \hat{b})_{11} \in \mathbb{R}$ is injective, and it is also continuous if $f$ is. But there is no injective continuous map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, per invariance of domain. Thus, $f$ cannot be continuous.
However, a noncontinuous $f$ satisfying the condition does exist. The construction is slightly tedious, but the basic idea is as follows: We first observe that a subgroup $H < S_n$ can be the stabilizer of a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (under the action of permuting coordinates) iff there is a partition $(A_1, \cdots, A_k)$ of $\{1, \cdots, n\}$ s.t. $H = \text{Sym}(A_1) \times \cdots \times \text{Sym}(A_k)$. Similar results hold for $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$. For possible stabilizers $H = \text{Sym}(A_1) \times \cdots \times \text{Sym}(A_k) < S_n$ and $G = \text{Sym}(B_1) \times \cdots \times \text{Sym}(B_l) < S_m$, we let $H \otimes G$ be,
$$H \otimes G = \prod_{i=1}^k \prod_{j=1}^l \text{Sym}(A_i \times B_k) < S_{n \times m}$$
which is a possible stabilizer for a point in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$.
Furthermore, for any $H < S_n$ which can be the stabilizer of some $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, there are always exactly continuum many $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\text{Stab}(x) = H$. Similar results hold for $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$. Let,
$$(\mathbb{R}^n)_H = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \text{Stab}(x) = H\}$$
We equip $(\mathbb{R}^n)_H$ with the equivalence relation $\sim$ generated by permutation action of $S_n$. Then $|(\mathbb{R}^n)_H/\sim| = \mathfrak{c}$. We also use similar notations for $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, and for them we have the same result on cardinalities.
Thus, for each pair of possible stabilizers $H < S_n$ and $G < S_m$, we may choose an injective map $f_{H, G}: [(\mathbb{R}^n)_H/\sim] \times [(\mathbb{R}^m)_G/\sim] \to (\mathbb{R}^{n \times m})_{H \otimes G}/\sim$. Fix a choice function $g$ with large enough domain so that it chooses a representative of each of the equivalence classes referenced above. Now, define $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ by,
$$f(\pi g([x]_\sim), \mu g([y]_\sim)) = (\pi \otimes \mu)g(f_{H, G}([x]_\sim, [y]_\sim))$$
for any pair of possible stabilizers $H < S_n$ and $G < S_m$, and for any $[x]_\sim \in (\mathbb{R}^n)_H$ and $[y]_\sim \in (\mathbb{R}^m)_G$. One may check this is indeed a well-defined injective function that commutes with permutations.
Remark: One thing to note here is that the conditions that $n \geq 2$ and $m \geq 2$ are irrelevant. Neither the proof that $f$ cannot be continuous nor the construction of a non-continuous example uses those conditions.

Yes my mistake thanks for clearing that up
